# Is there a way that I can use Azure SQL server as data source?

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

My project is currently built on Azure (data are stored in Azure SQL server), I am currently trying to introduce streaming/batching process ability to my project by leveraging PyFilnk. However，I didn't find any document about how to connect PyFlink to Azure SQL server, is there a way that I can use Azure SQL server as data source in PyFlink?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to dump some data from Azure SQL server to use as input for a batch Flink job, you could capture the result of a SQL query as a CSV file, and read that into Flink.

On the other hand, if you want to establish a live connection from Azure SQL server to a streaming Flink job, then look at using something like Debezium to do change data capture. You might be able to use Kafka connect or https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors for this.